# drop down list inside form.... how to trigger the action without button?

Tags: php, html

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="foo.php">

  sort by:
  <select>
  <option name="date">sort by date</option>
  <option name="name">sort by name</option>
  <option name="price">sort by price</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

What I want here is that when I select an option the action in the form will be automatically executed? so in short
what I select will be send in foo.php thru $_POST. I dont want input button to make the action executed.

Do I need Javascript to achieve this?
Can you show me code to do this?
if it needs javascript then how

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=js+submit+form+select+change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need javascript for that.

Although you should use [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), the basic code looks something like:

```
<select onChange="document.forms['form1'].submit();">
```

You attach an event handler to the `change` event and have it submit the form.

Comment: what if javascript in off what alternative should I do to do the sorting?

Comment: @user1729997 You can't. If javascript is off the form needs to be submitted manually by the visitor (using a button, etc.).

Comment: what about make a link for sorting that will be handle by GET in PHP

Comment: @user1729997 Sure, but then you'd have one link per option instead of a `select` element. That does not scale very well.

Comment: @jeroen can you also post the javascript code for attaching the event? I just really need it now, I promise I will learn it later.

Comment: @user1729997 That's what the `onChange="..."` does.

Comment: @jeroen ok thanks im so stupid for not running the code you gave thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This will require JavaScript, but if you are wiling to use jQuery then this is really easy. With jQuery it would be:

```
$('#form1 select').on('change', function() {
  $('#form1').submit();
});
```

In JavaScript you are binding the onChange event of the `select` element.  One way to do this is:

```
<select onChange="document.form1.submit()">
```

Comment: If he doesn't know how to perform this operation with plain JS, I don't think he is ready for a framework.

Comment: I don't know if I agree with that approach when it comes to jQuery.  I'm all about teaching a man to fish, but jQuery feels like the good parts of JavaScript minus some of the bad parts of the DOM :)

Comment: I guess that is true. I put a vote for you since you show two solutions.

Comment: I totally agree that this task by itself isn't worth including jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use javascript straight with your select element. The event is onChange.

```
 <select onchange="javascript:document.form1.submit();">
```

You can also go for jQuery based forms. Download jQuery javascript from http://jquery.com/ and include it in your HTML. After that, use :

```
 <select id="sort">
```

And, inside your  :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#sort").change(function() {
                    $(this).parent().submit();
           });
 });
```