# How to Post Input & Select type in single form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

In posting.php file i wrote below code. In single form i included both Input type [textfield] & Select [options] type and when i  submit form , i am getting error as `Notice: Undefined index: designerorder_id`

**Form**

```
<form  method="post">
<div id="ordernumbers">
          <select name ="designerorder_id">
            <option>Select Order</option>
          </select>
        </div>
<input type="text" name="paid_status" />

<input name="register1" type="submit"  onclick="return updatepayment(); "/>
```

**Php**

```
if (isset($_POST['register1'])) {

  $designerorder_id = trim($_POST['designerorder_id']);
  $paid_status = password_hash($_POST['paid_status'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

  $stmt = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details");
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $stmt->execute();


    if ($reg_user->register1($designerorder_id,  $paid_status)) {
      $id = $reg_user->lasdID();
      $key = base64_encode($id);
      $id = $key;

      $message = " updated database";

   //   $subject = "Confirm updation";

    //  $reg_user->send_mail($email, $message, $subject);
      $msg = "database updated ";

    } else {
      echo "sorry , Query could no execute...";
    }
  }
```

**script**

```
function getOrderDetail(e)
  {
    var designerId=e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;    
    var url="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/designerpaidstatus.php?designer_id="+designerId+"&opration=2";
       var request = jQuery.ajax( {
                url: url ,
                type: 'POST',                      
            } );

            request.done( function (result)
            {  
              document.getElementById('ordernumbers').innerHTML =result;

            } );
            request.fail( function ( error )
            {
                console.dir(error);             
            } );
     }
```

What i tried is ,

When i researched google, i found links  like  [link1](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-select.html) [link2](http://www.vasiljevski.com/blog/2012/01/17/how-to-set-the-selected-option-of-select-tag-from-the-php/)  , [link3](https://www.formget.com/php-select-option-and-php-radio-button/) which using only `Select [options]` [not input type ] inside form. in some other [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789468/drop-down-list-inside-form-how-to-trigger-the-action-without-button) they are using JS to achieve this, also i tried as in [link5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578559/php-html-send-html-select-option-attribute-in-post) and tried below kinds of code :

```
$selected_val = $_POST['designerorder_id'];
$stud = explode("_",$_POST['designerorder_id']);
```

but nothing working for me. i almost spent 2 days before asking question, i am completely new to php, please help me.

**Edit** - complete code of **posting.ph**p file

```
<?php 

require_once 'dbconfig.php';
require_once 'class.user.php';
include 'home.php';
print_r($_POST);
//$reg_user = new USER();
$reg_user='';


$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users");
  $stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']));
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $stmt->execute();
?>

<?php

var_dump($_POST);

  if (isset($_POST['register1'])) {



  $designerorder_id = trim($_POST['designerorder_id']);
//  $selected_val = $_POST['designerorder_id'];
//$stud = explode("_",$_POST['designerorder_id']);
  $product_id = trim($_POST['product_id']);
  $paid_status = password_hash($_POST['paid_status'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $due_date = trim($_POST['due_date']);

  $stmt = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details");
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $stmt->execute();


    if ($reg_user->register1($designerorder_id, $product_id, $paid_status, $due_date)) {
      $id = $reg_user->lasdID();
      $key = base64_encode($id);
      $id = $key;

      $message = " updated database";

   //   $subject = "Confirm updation";

    //  $reg_user->send_mail($email, $message, $subject);
      $msg = "database updated ";

    } else {
      echo "sorry , Query could no execute...";
    }
  }



?>

<style type="text/css">
  .paymentstatus{width:70%;margin: auto!important;}
  .inputpayment{/*width: 20%;clear:both;*/}
</style>


<div class="paymentstatus">
 <form class="form-signin" method="post"  action="posting.php" id="myFormId"> 
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Designer Payment Status</h2> 


    <table>


    <!-- Designer -->
      <tr>

        <td> Designer  </td>

        <td>
          <select onchange="getOrderDetail(event);" >
            <option>Select Designer</option>
            <?php while($data = $stmt->fetch())  { if($data['type']=="admin")continue;?>
              <option value="<?php echo $data['userID'];?>"><?php echo $data['name'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select> 
        </td> 

      </tr> 


     <!-- Designer Order Number: -->

    <tr>

        <td>Number: </td>

      <td>

        <div id="ordernumbers">
          <select name ="designerorder_id">
            <option>Select Order</option>
            <option value="1">abc</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      </td>

    </tr> 


      <!-- Product Related To Order Number:  -->

      <tr>  

        <td>Products</td>

        <td>

        <div id="productnumbers">
          <select name="product_id">
            <option>Select Products</option>
          </select>
          </div>

        </td>

      </tr>


      <!--  Paid Status: -->

      <tr>
        <td>Paid :</td>


        <td>
          <input type="text" class="inputpayment" placeholder="PaidStatus" name="paid_status" value="Paid" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>

      </tr>


      <!--  DueDate:-->

       <tr>
        <td>Due Date</td>


        <td>
          <input type="text" class="inputpayment" id="datepicker" placeholder="Duedate" name="due_date" value=""/>
        </td>
      </tr>



    </table>
    <hr/>


   <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" name="register1" type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Update Payment" onclick="return updatepayment(); "/>

  </form>

</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/bootstrap/css/jquery-ui.css"> 

<script src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/bootstrap/js/outthinking/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(

  /* This is the function that will get executed after the DOM is fully loaded */
  function () {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,//this option for allowing user to select month
      changeYear: true //this option for allowing user to select from year range
    });
  }

);
  function getOrderDetail(e)
  {
    var designerId=e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;  
//var designerId=e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].‌​value;  
    var url="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/designerpaidstatus.php?designer_id="+designerId+"&opration=2";
       var request = jQuery.ajax( {
                url: url ,
                type: 'POST',                      
            } );

            request.done( function (result)
            {  
              document.getElementById('ordernumbers').innerHTML =result;

            } );
            request.fail( function ( error )
            {
                console.dir(error);             
            } );
     }
  function getProductDetail(e)
  {    
    var productId = $("#dproductselect option:selected").attr("class");  
    var finalstrig=productId.split(",");
    alert(finalstrig[1]);
    var select='';
    select+='<select><option>Select Product</option>';

    for(i=0;i<finalstrig.length;i++)
    {
      if(finalstrig[i]!=0)
      {
        select +='<option value="'+finalstrig[i]+'">'+finalstrig[i]+'</option>';
      }
    }
    select +='</select>';   
    document.getElementById('productnumbers').innerHTML =select;
  }

</script>

<script>

var request = jQuery.ajax( {
                url: 'posting.php' ,
                data : jQuery("#myFormId").serialize(),
                type: 'POST',                      
            } );


</script>
```

**class.user.php**

```
public function register1($designerorder_id, $product_id, $paid_status, $due_date)
  {
    try {

      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO order_details(designerorder_id, product_id, paid_status, due_date) 
            VALUES(:designerorder_id, :product_id, :paid_status, :due_date) ;");
      $stmt->execute(array(
          ":designerorder_id" => $designerorder_id,
          ":product_id" => $product_id,
          ":paid_status" => $paid_status,
          ":due_date" => $due_date

      ));
      return $stmt;
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
      echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
  }
```

Comment: use `isset()` method to check `designerorder_id` is set or not

Comment: @Karthi when i tried code : `if (isset($_POST["designerorder_id"]) && !empty($_POST["designerorder_id"])) {
    echo "Yes, mail is set";    
}else{  
    echo "N0, mail is not set";
}`  , i got this result `N0, mail is not setarray(0) { }`

Comment: yes thats the problem .

Comment: @Karthi please tell how i can set the `designerorder_id` , i researched in entire google, all mentioned how to set if there is only `selected options`, they did't mentioned if there is both `input type & selected options inside form`......

Comment: okay lets clear your question first bcz im not understand. what you need. missing `<option>Select Order</option>` values and why used here `SELECT * FROM .....` query

Comment: @Karthi in single form , i am including 2 types of values - one is `input type' : `<input type="text" name="paid_status" />` , another one is `<select name ="designerorder_id">` , user will enter value in input fiels & select values , so i want to save both values in database.... but when i submit form , i am getting error : `Notice: Undefined index: designerorder_id`

Comment: okay good its simple one wait

Comment: @RamRaider Thanks for suggestion, but when i tried `var designerId=e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].‌​value;` dropdown values of selected field disappeared.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128424/discussion-between-karthi-and-abcd).

Comment: form action is missing `<form  action="posting.php" method="post">`

Comment: @RohitJindal  Thanks , i tried that code,     still getting same error : `Notice: Undefined index: designerorder_id`  in line `$designerorder_id = trim($_POST['designerorder_id']);`

Comment: @abcd Check the answer. I tried in phpfiddle.org and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `<select name= "designerorder_id">` remove space after name attribute, it should be `<select name="designerorder_id">`

Then give some id to the form like this:

```
<form  method="post" id="myFormId">
```

And in the ajax form pass the form data like this:

```
var request = jQuery.ajax( {
                url: url ,
                data : jQuery("#myFormId").serialize(),
                type: 'POST',                      
            } );
```

And as I can see you are sending the data in the ajax with post method so why to use get variables in your URL string ?

Pass your other required variables and its value using the `<input type="hidden">`.

It would be the simple way I guess.

Also some changes are required  in your function `function getProductDetail(e)`. You have written:

```
select+='<select><option>Select Product</option>';
```

change it to `select+='<select name="product_id"><option>Select Product</option>';`

Remove this code:

```
        var request = jQuery.ajax( {
            url: 'posting.php' ,
            data : jQuery("#myFormId").serialize(),
            type: 'POST',                      
        } );
```

If you are refreshing the page you don't need this.

In your PHP code change `$paid_status = password_hash($_POST['paid_status'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` to `$paid_status = $_POST['paid_status'];`.

Comment: Thanks , i tried your code by changing `url: 'posting.php' ,` , still i am getting same error, is i need to change anything else ?

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: designerorder_id` in line `$designerorder_id = trim($_POST['designerorder_id']);`

Comment: what is your server side code ?   print all the POST variables and check the values.   use  `print_r($_POST)`  once check what variables and values you are getting ,

Comment: `Array ( [paid_status] => Paid [due_date] => 11/06/2016 [register1] => Update Payment )` i got this result.....

Comment: @abcd , please join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128429/jquery-ajax-problems

Comment: `<select name ="designerorder_id">`  remove space after name attribute.

Comment: @abcd , buddy i am in middle of something, Please wait , will catch you soon

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in [phpfiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/) and it is working fine.

**Code :**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<div id="ordernumbers">
          <select name ="designerorder_id">
            <option>Select Order</option>
            <option value="One">One</option>  
          </select>
        </div>
<input type="text" name="paid_status" />

<input name="register1" type="submit"  onclick="return updatepayment(); "/> <br><br>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['register1'])) {

  $designerorder_id = trim($_POST['designerorder_id']);
     echo $designerorder_id;  
}
?>
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: I am not sure about your library files. I tried my best. Thanks

Comment: Thanks , i removed space after name attribute  here :  `<select name ="designerorder_id">`, now that one solved , now i am getting error : `Notice: Undefined index: product_id`

Comment: @RohitJindal , he got whitespace after name attribute with select , thats the problem,

Comment: @PunitGajjar  In my answer white space is there but it is not creating any problem . so, white space was not the problem.

Comment: @abcd there is no element with name as `product_id` in html.that's why it is giving you this error.

Answer (score -1):

can you please change your **form** and try

```
<form  method="post">
    <div id="ordernumbers">
              <select name ="designerorder_id">
                 <option value="">Select Order</option>
                <option value="1">abc</option>
              </select>
            </div>
    <input type="text" name="paid_status" />

    <input name="register1" type="submit"  onclick="return updatepayment(); "/>
```

Comment: Thanks , i tried that code,     still getting same error : `Notice: Undefined index: designerorder_id`  in line `$designerorder_id = trim($_POST['designerorder_id']);`

Comment: whats the difference between your form and his? stop giving incomplete answers, @abcd why are you rewarding a bad answer?

Comment: @abcd -can you please add one or more option value and try?

Comment: @Masivuye Cokile - I tried this code and i didn't get any 'error', I am sorry if my answer is incomplete.

Comment: @Shanukk i tried by ading this code : `<option value="1">abc</option>` , still same error....